# Unable to read sim number

Tags: android

Reading Sim number gives exception. How to get unique identification for activation to avoid multiple user activation from one key. I don't want to use google play services or google play in app purchases. therefore please help me to obtain unique identification for each devices.

Answer (score 1):

After android 8, there is a way to get a unique key called a software key. Check below for implementation.

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

This key depends on the device serial number, user id, and software package. So this might not use full for your requirement. Therefore read this article.

https://www.google.com/search?q=android+id&rlz=1C5CHFA_enLK902LK902&oq=Android+id&aqs=chrome.0.0i67j0j0i20i263j0l2j69i60l3.2956j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: This is working you made my day